# Unexpected 'is' operator result

Tags: c#

Testing for the DateTimeOffSet using the 'is' operator never passes.  In the following sample I know the DateTimeOffset type is one of the properties but it never returns True.  Thanks for helping me understand why?

```
foreach (var prop in qSOs.GetListType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.PropertyType); // System.DateTimeOffset

    if (prop.PropertyType is System.DateTimeOffset) // Never returns True
    {
        var p = prop.Name;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because PropertyType is a [Type] object, not a date time object...

try:

```
if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTimeOffset)) 
{
    var p = prop.Name;
}
```

**Is** is for checking the type, i.e.

```
var maybeAStringOrMaybeAnInt = GetSomeRandomType();
if (maybeAStringOrMaybeAnInt is String)
```